# How do I append another field in the ReactJS conditional statement?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to append a `<br/>` tag between the `record.customerName` and the `record.customerGender` in the conditional statement but it is giving me the `<br/>` instead of a real break? How do I append a break between the 2 frields? Thanks

```
{customeData.map(record =>{
return(<React.Fragment>{record._id == items._id? record.customerName + '<br/>' + record.customerGender:""}</React.Fragment>)
                                        })}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just throw raw HTML into JSX expressions.

Use JSX properly. Put your string variables in expressions, and generate your elements with JSX tags.

```
(record) => {
    return (record._id == items._id) ?
        <>
            {record.customerName}
            <br />
            {record.customerGender}
        </> :
        "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, much simpler.

```js
{customeData.map(record => (
  record._id === items._id && (
    <>
      {record.customerName}
      <br />
      {record.customerGender}
    </>
  )
))}
```

I've also taken the liberty of cleaning up your code a little.
If you need an explanation regarding some factors of the cleanups, or if something doesn't work properly, please let me know.